# Matter js - svg path with holes does not display correctly

Tags: javascript, svg, convex-hull, physics-engine, matter.js

I am trying to render an svg path with the physics engine Matter JS. The path renders with Matter JS, but it doesn't render the way it should. My understanding is that I first need to load pathseg (https://github.com/progers/pathseg), which is what I am doing:

```
var url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/progers/pathseg/master/pathseg.js';

loadGitHubScript(url).then(function() {

  var path = '<svg id="Ebene_1" data-name="Ebene 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
  style="enable-background:new 0 0 512 512;" viewBox="0 0 73.64 63.03"><path class="cls-1" 
  d="M333.85,415.22l-25.57-16.45V446.7l27,2.85Zm-18,22.24v-18l9.06,1.61,2,17.21Z" 
  transform="translate(-261.61 -386.53)"/></svg>';

  var vertices = Matter.Svg.pathToVertices(path);
  var body = Bodies.fromVertices(200, 200, vertices, options);
  World.add(engine.world, body);

});
```

The result is the image on the left side, whereas it should really look like the image on the right side. How can I prevent this from happening?

[image]

Comment: Just a suggestion - may want to space out your path data string in case the parser has a bug in its regex parsing. d="M333.85 415.22 l -25.57 -16.45 V446.7 l 27 2.85Z m -18 22.24 v -18 l 9.06 1.61  2 17.21 Z"

Comment: The [`Matter.Bodies.fromVertices` docs](https://brm.io/matter-js/docs/classes/Bodies.html#method_fromVertices) say: "Note that this process is not guaranteed to support complex sets of vertices (e.g. those with holes may fail)".